# Can't download app after testing it

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have been developing a Xamarin Forms app and have tested the app on my Samsung Galaxy S7. The app ran fine and so I uploaded it to the play store as an alpha version. I was able to download that version onto my phone, thus having 2 copies of the app on my phone. Recently I made a few updates and after trying to debug the app on my device, I decided to release the app as a beta version despite not being able to test the app on my device. I haven't been able to download the app from the play store since and I still can't test my app on my device. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Manually delete the app from your phone via Settings/Apps... Or use `adb` to uninstall it. `adb uninstall your.package.name`

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention that both the test app version and the downloaded version were deleted and I can't find those on my phone.

Comment: When you download the app, any message shows on the device ?

Comment: The play store just crashes. I managed to fix it by downloading the app to my phone through my computer browser.